# How to update column based on select statement result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with following columns :

**SalaryStructure:**

```
Id   StructureName   IsApplicable  IsActive

IsApplicable - bit, not null
```

"`IsApplicable`" is a newly added column which has all the values as "`false`" by default.

Now, I want to update "`IsApplicable`" based on pattern matching logic and then set the value of "`IsApplicable`" based on that.

Query:

```
SELECT 
        CASE 
        WHEN (StructureName LIKE '%Associate1%' OR StructureName Like '%Tier1%') 
        THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS IsApplicable,
    FROM SalaryStructure
        WHERE IsActive = 0
```

I want to run above script on same table **SalaryStructure** and update the values "`Yes`" and "`No`" in the column "`IsApplicable`".

But I am not getting how to include this part in "Update" statement. I want update all the records in the **SalaryStructure** table.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `'Yes'` or `'No'` are valid `bit` values, a non-`NULL`able `bit` column can store `1` or `0` and that is it. I therefore assume `'No'` should be `0` and `'Yes'` should be `1`.

As for the `UPDATE` it would, in truth, look like another other `UPDATE` on a single table. `UPDATE...SET...WHERE`:

```sql
UPDATE dbo.SalaryStructure
SET IsApplicable = CASE WHEN (StructureName LIKE '%Associate1%' OR StructureName LIKE '%Tier1%') THEN 0
                        ELSE 1
                   END
WHERE IsActive = 0;
```

Comment: This works fine for me. Thank you so much. Really appreciate it